# Requests to WAN IP are served by LAN interface on OpenWrt

Tags: networking, iptables, port-forwarding, openwrt

Here's the situation. I have OpenWrt installation with multiple zones:

- WAN - let it be 1.1.1.1
- LAN0 - 192.168.0.0/24
- LAN1 - 192.168.1.0/24

After forwarding some port from `WAN` to `LAN0` I can reach it from another host in the Internet (e.g. `2.2.2.2`) but I can't reach port from `LAN1`.
After some researchments I discovered that for some reason any packets I send from `LAN0/1` to `1.1.1.1` are being served from correspoding LAN interface, but not WAN e.g. when I'm trying to connect to `1.1.1.1:80` from `LAN1` the packets not being forwarded to `LAN0` but to router (it opens its web interface).

Yeah, I could make duplicate for every forwarding rule but I really want to try to avoid it as there are already 10 of them.
Is there any way to properly configure firewall (maybe raw iptables but w/o DNAT that only accepts one interface as an argument?) or to make packets from LAN0/1 to public IP being recieved by WAN interface?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning and tell if this describes the kind of solution you are looking for. Just to be sure of the problem. I guess you'll have to provide your iptables rules (eg: `iptables-save -c`).

Comment: @A.B seems like that's the problem and in most cases where two hosts are in the same LAN turning on NAT loopback solves the problem. In my case there are 2 LANs so option seems not to work unfortunately

Comment: Actually that's not really an hairpinning situation if it's between two different LANs. But only the NAT rules (and routes) can explain what happens and why.